# How to use the symmetry of a function to find the analytical expression of a function on a certain interval?

Tags: functions

The domain of the function f[x] is R,

And f[x] is an odd function `f[-x] == -f[x]`

Also satisfying that `f[1-x]+f[1+x]==2`.

When x belongs to the closed interval [0,1], `f[x]=2x- x^2`,

> 2x-x^2 only define on the interval 0<=x<=1. We extend it by the two conditions f[x]=-f[-x] and f[x]=2-f[2-x] to all the Reals domain.

by cvgmt

How to use software to find the analytical expression of the function on the interval [-1,0] based on the known conditions above?

Furthermore, arbitrarily specify an interval, such as [10,20], and find the corresponding analytical formula on the interval?

Comment: Is this a follow up to your [closed question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296635/how-to-draw-the-graph-of-function-fx)?  I Think user cvgmt answered your question in his last comment!

Comment: It's not the same problem, the closed problem is how to draw the function graph. This problem is to find the function expression corresponding to a certain interval

Comment: I would expect that `Simplify` with user defined transformation rules should do that. This does not work however...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `f[-x] == -f[x]` means that the graph is point reflection respect to `{0,0}`.
- `f[1-x]+f[1+x]==2` means that the graph is point reflection respect to `{1,1}` since for two points `{x1,y1}={1-x,f[1-x]}` and `{x2,y2}={1+x,f[1+x]}`, `(x1+x2)/2=((1-x)+(1+x))/2=1` and `(y1+y2)/2=(f[1-x]+f[1+x])/2=1`.
- I do not believe that Mathematica can do this automatic.Here we directly construct such expression by `Mod`.( The idea is that we move or rotation `180 Degree`  along direction `{1,1}-{0,0}`).

```
Clear["Global`*"];
g[x_] := 2 x - x^2;
G[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{g[Mod[x, 2, 0]] + x - Mod[x, 2, 0], 
     0 <= Mod[x, 2, 0] <= 1}, {-g[-Mod[x, 2, -1]] + x - 
      Mod[x, 2, -1], -1 <= Mod[x, 2, -1] <= 0}}];
Plot[G[x], {x, -6, 6}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, Mesh -> {Range[-6, 6]}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Cyan}]
```

[image]

### Try to do the more general cases

for two arbitrary point reflection.(Here we according to `{x1, y1} = {2, 3};{x2, y2} = {5, 8};` instead of `{x1,y1}={0,0};{x2,y2}={1,1};`

```
Clear["Global`*"];
g[x_] := 2  x - x^2;
r[a_, b_][f_] := (2  b + #) &@*Minus@*f@*((2  a - #) &);
{x1, y1} = {2, 3};
{x2, y2} = {5, 8};
(*{x1,y1}={0,0};
{x2,y2}={1,1};*)
fun[x_, n_Integer] := 
  Module[{maps}, 
   maps = Which[n == 0, Identity, n > 0 && n ∈ Integers, 
     PadRight[{r[x2, y2], r[x1, y1]}, n, "Periodic"], 
     n < 0 && n ∈ Integers, 
     PadRight[{r[x1, y1], r[x2, y2]}, -n, "Periodic"]];
   Apply[Composition][maps][g][x] // Simplify];
Show[Table[
  Plot[fun[x, k] // Evaluate, {x, x1 + k  (x2 - x1), 
    x2 + k  (x2 - x1)}], {k, -5, 5}], 
 Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[5], Red, Point@{x1, y1}, Purple, 
   Point@{x2, y2}}], PlotRange -> All]
Grid[Table[{x1 + k  (x2 - x1) < x < x2 + k  (x2 - x1), 
   fun[x, k]}, {k, -5, 5}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This universal code is very powerful. By inputting a known analytical formula for a certain interval and the coordinates of two symmetric points, the function graph is drawn and the corresponding analytical formula for the interval is generated

Answer (score 4):

Using @cvgmt definition of `G` we can find analytic definition in each interval `(n,n+1)` for integer `n`. But the function is not analytic on any larger interval so for `(10,20)` you can not have analytic definition, only definition in a piecewise form.

```
g[x_] := 2 x - x^2;
G[x_] := Piecewise[{{g[Mod[x, 2, 0]] + x - Mod[x, 2, 0], 
     0 <= Mod[x, 2, 0] <= 1}, {-g[-Mod[x, 2, -1]] + x - 
      Mod[x, 2, -1], -1 <= Mod[x, 2, -1] <= 0}}];

Table[{n < x < n + 1, 
   Expand@FullSimplify[G[x], Assumptions -> n < x < n + 1]},
   {n, -5, 5}] // Column
```

---

```
{
 {{-5 < x < -4, 20 + 10 x + x^2}},
 {{-4 < x < -3, -12 - 6 x - x^2}},
 {{-3 < x < -2, 6 + 6 x + x^2}},
 {{-2 < x < -1, -2 - 2 x - x^2}},
 {{-1 < x < 0, 2 x + x^2}},
 {{0 < x < 1, 2 x - x^2}},
 {{1 < x < 2, 2 - 2 x + x^2}},
 {{2 < x < 3, -6 + 6 x - x^2}},
 {{3 < x < 4, 12 - 6 x + x^2}},
 {{4 < x < 5, -20 + 10 x - x^2}},
 {{5 < x < 6, 30 - 10 x + x^2}}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Which` gives the implicit function definition in the real domain

```
f[x_] := Which[ 0 <= x <= 1, 2 x - x^2, x > 1, 2 - f [2 - x],x < 0, -f [-x]]

Plot[f[x],{x,-Pi,  E}]
```

[image]

**addendum**

Similar to cvgmt 's answer a more explicit compact  definition might be `f[x]=x(2-Abs[x]) , -1<x<1` using Mod

```
g[x_] :=  Block[{xmod = Mod[x, 2, -1 ], fx = Floor[x] },
If[EvenQ[fx], fx -= 1];  
Mean[{fx, fx + 2}] + xmod (2  - Abs[xmod]) ] 

Show[Table[
ParametricPlot[{x + u, g[x + u]}, {x, -1, 1},PlotStyle -> andomColor[]], {u, Range[-4, 4, 2]}],PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0,0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way, using `DSolve` to construct the piecewise solution. Works for any interval.

```
reflectedF = 2 x - x^2 // Piecewise[{{#, x > 0}}, -# /. x -> -x] &;
solF = DSolveValue[{f'[x] == D[reflectedF /. x -> Mod[x, 2, -1], x], 
     f[0] == 0}, f[x], {x, -5, 8}] // PiecewiseExpand;

Plot[solF, {x, -5, 8}]
```

[image]