# How to use Floor and Mod to construct consistent bisymmetric function according to requirements?

Tags: functions

The domain of the function f [x] is R,

where `f[-x-1]=- f[x-1]`, that is, f[x] is about {-1,0} is centrally symmetric,

and `f[-x+1]==f[x+1]`, that is, f[x] is axisymmetric about the line x==1,
When the interval `-1<x<=1`,`f[x]=- x^2+1`

You can use the following code to draw the function graph

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := 
  Which[-1 < x < 1, 1 - x^2, x > 1, f[-x + 2], x < -1, -f[-x - 2]];
Plot[{f[x]}, {x, -7, 13}]
f[7/2]
```

[image]

How can we use Floor and Mod to construct the same function, and then use Table to find the analytical expression of the function corresponding to a certain interval. What is the method of constructing this?

This type of problem can be classified into three forms based on the bisymmetry of functions. The first type is a function that is symmetric about the centers of two points; The second type is the function being symmetric about a point center and a straight line axis; The third type is a function that is axisymmetric about two straight lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To get the expression automatic, we can do this similar to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/296684/72111, that is we define two  transformations act on the function, one is `r[a,b][f]` point reflection respect to point `{a,b}` and `t[c][f]` symmetric to line `x==c`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
g[x_] := 1 - x^2;
r[a_, b_][f_] := (2    b + #) &@*Minus@*f@*((2    a - #) &);
t[c_][f_] := f@*((2  c - #) &);
{x1, y1} = {-1, 0};
x2 = 1;
fun[x_, n_Integer] := 
  Module[{maps}, 
   maps = Which[n == 0, Identity, n > 0 && n ∈ Integers, 
     PadRight[{t[x2], r[x1, y1]}, n, "Periodic"], 
     n < 0 && n ∈ Integers, 
     PadRight[{r[x1, y1], t[x2]}, -n, "Periodic"]];
   Apply[Composition][maps][g][x] // Simplify];
Show[Table[
  Plot[fun[x, k] // Evaluate, {x, x1 + k    (x2 - x1), 
    x2 + k    (x2 - x1)}], {k, -5, 5}], 
 Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[5], Red, Point@{x1, y1}, Purple, Dashed, 
   InfiniteLine[{x2, 0}, {0, 1}]}], PlotRange -> All]
Grid[Table[{x1 + k    (x2 - x1) < x < x2 + k    (x2 - x1), 
   fun[x, k]}, {k, -5, 5}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

- Since `x1 + k    (x2 - x1) < x < x2 + k    (x2 - x1)` imply that `k=Ceiling[(x-x2)/(x2-x1)]==Floor[(x-x1)/(x2-x1)]`

```
F[x_] := Module[{k}, k = Floor[(x - x1)/(x2 - x1)]; fun[x, k]];
F[7/2]
Plot[F[x], {x, -7, 13}]
```

[image]

- The case reflect by two lines. Here we use two reflections `t[x2], t[x1]`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
g[x_] := 1 - x^2;
t[c_][f_] := f@*((2   c - #) &);
x1 = -2;
x2 = 1;
fun[x_, n_Integer] := 
  Module[{maps}, 
   maps = Which[n == 0, Identity, n > 0 && n ∈ Integers, 
     PadRight[{t[x2], t[x1]}, n, "Periodic"], 
     n < 0 && n ∈ Integers, 
     PadRight[{t[x1], t[x2]}, -n, "Periodic"]];
   Apply[Composition][maps][g][x] // Simplify];
Show[Table[
  Plot[fun[x, k] // Evaluate, {x, x1 + k     (x2 - x1), 
    x2 + k     (x2 - x1)}], {k, -5, 5}], 
 Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[5], Red, Dashed, Dashed, 
   InfiniteLine[{x1, 0}, {0, 1}], Purple, Dashed, 
   InfiniteLine[{x2, 0}, {0, 1}]}], PlotRange -> All]
Grid[Table[{x1 + k     (x2 - x1) < x < x2 + k     (x2 - x1), 
   fun[x, k]}, {k, -5, 5}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: What if the function is axisymmetric about two straight lines?

Comment: For example, the axes of symmetry are x1==1 and x2==3

Comment: @csn899  I have post the case `x1 = -2;
x2 = 1;`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, these codes are very useful!

Comment: How to input the value of this function when x=7/2?

Comment: ```Clear[f];
f[x_] := Module[{k}, k = Floor[(x - x1)/(x2 - x1)]; fun[x, k]];

f[7/2]
```The calculated function value is incorrect

Comment: @csn899 No, `-3/4` is right.  `-1 + (-4 + x)^2 /. x -> 7/2`

Comment: This function with double symmetry generally has periodicity (when the function is symmetric about the center of two points, the y-axis of the points needs to be equal). Why use FunctionPeriod [F [x], x] to calculate the function period as 0?

Comment: @csn899  Since `F[x]` not a directly symbol expression, `FunctionPeriod [F [x], x]` does not work.

Comment: The code only inputs the function expression and symmetry of a certain interval in the known conditions. How does the code ensure that the function image is correct without entering the interval where the expression is located? What principle?